# Dynamically Create,Move And Resize The Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, controls

I have a Code Which Create a TextBox In Run Time and Also Resize and Move the pre-created Controls.
The Problem i am facing is i cannot resize or Move the Control which I create During the Run time.

Here is the Code.

```
  public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox AddNewTextBox()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.Controls.Add(txt);
            txt.Top = cLeft * 25;
            txt.Left = 100;
            txt.Text = "TextBox " + this.cLeft.ToString();
            cLeft = cLeft + 1;
            return txt;
        }
        private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddNewTextBox();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    ControlMoverOrResizer.Init(textBox1);

            cboWorkType.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
```

The problem I am facing is I don't know how to refer the Newly created Textbox in

```
ControlMoverOrResizer.Init(textBox1);
```

I tried to Call

> txt.Text

But it is throwing the error of
cannot convert String to Windows.form.controls.

Please Guide me where I am making mistake.
Thanks

Comment: It is not very obvious which control you want to move, considering that your code creates multiple of them.  Start fixing it by keeping track of them in a `List<TextBox>`.  Or consider a DataGridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need somewhere to reference from. Maybe add your textboxes to a dictionary.

```
private Dictionary<string, TextBox> dynamicTextBoxes = new Dictionary<string, TextBox>();

public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox AddNewTextBox()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
    this.Controls.Add(txt);
    dynamicTextBoxes.Add($"tb{cLeft}", txt);
    txt.Top = cLeft * 25;
    txt.Left = 100;
    txt.Text = "TextBox " + this.cLeft.ToString();
    cLeft = cLeft + 1;
    return txt;
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ControlMoverOrResizer.Init(dynamicTextBoxes[$"tb{cLeft - 1}"]);
    cboWorkType.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Note: this will only ever move the last added textbox!

Comment: This Code is just Moving the Text Box not resizing it. How can i Access that property?

Comment: Actually, Got it.

Comment: The Multiline property was not set to true. Just set it to true and then can easily resize and move it. Thank you very much

Comment: hi your method helped me alot can you please help me in another problem. i want to remove the control as well can you guide me how to do that?

Comment: Firstly you would need to get the textbox, eg `var textbox = dynamicTextBoxes[$"tb{cLeft - 1}"];`. Then remove it from the dictionary and the controls collection, `this.Controls.Remove(textbox);` `dynamicTextBoxes.Remove(textbox);`

Comment: It's throwing an error of cannot convert from system.windows.forms.textbox to string

Comment: And it's only removing the last created control. How can we remove each on every button click.

Comment: so maybe `dynamicTextBoxes.Remove($"tb{cLeft - 1}");` and `cLeft--;`

Answer (score 1):

You have to get a reference to the control. Either store it as a field in your form, Or give it a `Name` and find it later in the controls collection.

If you only add one text box then it's easy:

**Method 1:**
Add a field to your form, and assign it when you create the `TextBox`

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.myTextBox = AddNewTextBox();
}
```

Later:

```
ControlMoverOrResizer.Init(this.myTextBox);
```

**Method 2:** Give it name and find it dynamically later:

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var txt = AddNewTextBox();
    txt.Name = "MyTextBox";
}
```

Later:

```
ControlMoverOrResizer.Init(this.Controls["MyTextBox"]);
```

*Note that if you add more than one `TextBox` you will have to adapt this code a bit*

Comment: I have to add up to 3 textboxes.

Comment: Then put them in a dictionary or give them a Name and find them later with Controls.Find

Comment: hi your method helped me alot can you please help me in another problem. i want to remove the control as well can you guide me how to do that?